# How to properly encrypt string in C# using rijndael and password

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords, rijndael

Ok, so I've done some research and I think that I've found an answer:

- Use password and salt to create fitting key.
- Generate random IV
- Use RijndaelManaged class to encrypt a string
- set first 16 bytes of output to IV in plaintext followed by the actual encrypted data

the whole thing is in this class:

```
public class AesEncrypt : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Lenght of <see cref="RijndaelManaged.IV"/>. Bytes of this lenght are
        /// prepended to every encryped string and contain IV itself
        /// </summary>
        private int IVSize => _rijndael.BlockSize / 8;

        /// <summary>
        /// Instantialzes new <see cref="AesEncrypt"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">password protecting the string</param>
        /// <param name="salt">salt which is used to hash password</param>
        public AesEncrypt(string key, byte[] salt)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salt));
            if (salt.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Argument is empty collection", nameof(salt));

            Salt = salt;
            _rijndael = new RijndaelManaged { Key = GetKey(key) };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Salt used to hash password to generate <see cref="RijndaelManaged.Key"/> to be used
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] Salt { get; }

        private readonly RijndaelManaged _rijndael;

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates key from password of any lenght and hash. Key is 256bit long.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">Any password</param>
        /// <returns>Key of fixed size 256bit</returns>
        protected byte[] GetKey(string password)
        {
            int keyLength = 32;//

            using (var pbkdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Salt))
            {
                return pbkdf.GetBytes(keyLength);
            }
        }
        protected ICryptoTransform GetEncryptor()
        {
            return _rijndael.CreateEncryptor();
        }
        protected ICryptoTransform GetDecryptor()
        {
            return _rijndael.CreateDecryptor(_rijndael.Key, _rijndael.IV);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts string to bytes using 256bit Rijndael. IV of size <see cref="IVSize"/> occupies first bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">Text to be encoded</param>
        /// <returns>Cipher in bytes</returns>
        public byte[] Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            if (plainText == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainText));

            _rijndael.GenerateIV();
            var encryptor = GetEncryptor();

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    //result without prepended IV
                    byte[] encBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                    #region prepend IV to the beginning of bytes
                    byte[] result = new byte[encBytes.Length + IVSize];
                    for (int i = 0; i < IVSize; i++)
                    {
                        //write IV to the beginning
                        result[i] = _rijndael.IV[i];
                    }
                    #endregion

                    for (int i = 0; i < encBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //index to be written to
                        int index = i + IVSize;
                        result[index] = encBytes[i];
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt a cipher made by <see cref="Encrypt"/> with known <see cref="Salt"/> and password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipher">Cipher to be decrypted.</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted string</returns>
        public string Decrypt(byte[] cipher)
        {
            if (cipher == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipher));
            if (cipher.Length < IVSize + 1) throw new ArgumentException($"Argument must be {IVSize + 1} bytes long at least!", nameof(cipher));

            #region read first IVSize bytes which are IV
            byte[] iv = new byte[IVSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < IVSize; i++)
            {
                iv[i] = cipher[i];
            }
            _rijndael.IV = iv;
            #endregion

            //actual bytes to be decrypted
            byte[] encBytes = new byte[cipher.Length - IVSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < encBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                //index to be read from
                int index = i + IVSize;
                encBytes[i] = cipher[index];
            }

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            var decryptor = GetDecryptor();

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encBytes))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _rijndael?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

It works, but I just want to ask this:

- is it safe?
- How do I identify an incorrect password?

Concerning wrong password detection I thought of writing the hash of original string after the IV, but which algorithm use then for hashing?

Comment: Both of the question can be answered with: *Use an authenticated mode of operation*.

Comment: @ArtjomB. would you please provide some link to begin with? I'd appreciate one with actual code.